# Git for Win + includeIf personal/work account

Tags: git, git-bash

I'd like to setup my git config with different personal/work accounts but the work account is never loaded.

Win10, Git for Windows v2.35.1(2), Git bash shell

`~/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    name = Personal
    email = personal@personal.com
[includeIf "gitdir/i:D/Projects/Work/"]
    path = .gitconfig-work
```

`~/.gitconfig-work`

```
[user]
    name = Work
    email = work@work.com
```

If I `git init` a new repo inside the work folder, e.g. `D:\Projects\Work\repo` and issue

```
git config --show-origin --get user.email
```

it shows:

```
file:C:/Users/<my-user>/.gitconfig  personal@personal.com
```

I have the latest git, use the case insensitive `gitdir` switch and the end "/" in the path.

Anything that I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're only missing a colon (`:`) in the gitdir path, so it should be:

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:D:/Projects/Work/"]
```

instead of:

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:D/Projects/Work/"]
```

Comment: Doh, correct! It should be a valid Win path, not Unix-style. Good eye, thanks!